# Is there a function that creates a list of rows from a python dataframe?

Tags: python

```
s1 = pd.Series([5, 6, 7])
s2 = pd.Series([7, 8, 9])

df = pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2)],  columns =  ["A", "B", "C"])

   A  B  C
0  5  6  7
1  8  9  1
```

and I need : [5,6,7,8,9,1]

Is there a function that does this directly?

Comment: Why do you not need `[5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9]`?

Comment: Please check your spelling. Desired output makes little sense.

Comment: Yea, what is the point and also this question isn't very clear. What exactly do you need and why?

Comment: Did something happen to `s2` in your example? I don't understand how the `1` got into your output, and where did your initial `7` from `s2` go?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the dataframe to a numpy array and ravel at any time:

```
df.to_numpy().ravel()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just `stack` the dataframe which will create single columnar series, then call `tolist()`

```py
>>> df.stack().to_list()
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]
```

Comment: How do you get `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]`? I get `[5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9]`. Or is that a typo by OP?

Comment: Yeah, that's a typo. I just copied the dataframe and read it from clipboard. Just copy the dataframe, and use `pd.read_clipboard()`, you will get that dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use numpy, here is an alternative:

```
df.T.melt()['value'].to_list()
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but it will have worse performance because of the need to Transpose the dataframe then melting it.

Comment: I know, this is why I upvoted your solution :)
But this is an alternative, just for ideas

Comment: Yeah, having an alternative is a good thing to have, and actually `df.to_numpy().ravel())` will be the most efficient I guess since it directly works with numpy.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
import numpy as np
np.ravel(df).tolist()
```

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that your output was typed in incorrectly. Here is my take on the output. Unfortunately, it's not "one function".

```py
result = [x for y in df.itertuples(False) for x in y]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try converting it too a list.

```
import numpy

numpy.ravel(df).tolist()
```